# xgboost not providing reproducible predictions after saving in bin format

Tags: r, save, logistic-regression, xgboost, file-format

I am having an issue where xgboost is not producing reproducible results after saving it to binary file.

R version: 4.1.2
XGBoost version 1.5.2.1

The methodology is as follows (logistic-regression, gbtree):

```
bst <- xgboost(
                params = best.params
                , data = dtrain
                , nrounds = nrounds
                , early_stopping_rounds = early_stopping_rounds
                , nthread = nthread
                , num_parallel_tree = num_parallel_tree
                , eval_metric =  eval_metric
                , verbose = 2  
                , print_every_n = 1
)

min(predict(bst, dtest))
max(predict(bst, dtest))
xgb.save(bst, savefilemodelloc)
```

this produces:
min = 0.17932555079
max = 0.78802382946

now I read the bin back in

```
remove(bst)
bst <- xgb.load(savefilemodelloc)
min(predict(bst, dtest))
max(predict(bst, dtest))
```

this produces:
min = 0.49377295375
max = 0.50564271212

this is being run on the exact same data set, and is producing no where near the same results.  I have tried rebuilding the model several times with nearly identical results.
The model size is about 17GB.
My OS is RHEL 7

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Update 3.8.2022
I have discovered that if I load my parameters back into the model manually it works.
for example

```
remove(bst)
bst <- xgb.load(savefilemodelloc)
xgb.parameters(bst) <- best.params
min(predict(bst, dtest))
max(predict(bst, dtest))
```

this now produces:
min = 0.17932555079
max = 0.78802382946

I am not sure if this is expected behavior

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried creating a reproducible example, but couldn't.  It appears to be related to this particular project as I have never experienced this before.  The data is not public.

Comment: Please file an [issue on xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen++save). Then again, they already have an issue on deprecating BIN format. Documenting issues with BIN would likely be useful mainly to motivate people to stop using it.

Comment: What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this issue before and I 'solved it' by saving the model in .rds format. My predictions weren't as extreme (<1% different before/after save/import) but I think it was to do with 'losing' specific parameters from the xgboost model object (something to do with 'early stopping'?) when the model was saved using `xgb.save()`.

I saved the model as:

Text

```
xgboost::xgb.dump(model = xgb,
                  fname = "xgb_model_text.txt",
                  with_stats = TRUE, dump_format = c("text"))
```

Binary

```
xgboost::xgb.save(model = xgb, fname = "xgb.model")
```

R object (.rds)

```
saveRDS(object = xgb, file = "xgb.model.rds")
```

And I also saved the feature names to a file (super useful down the track, highly recommend):

```
# Write the model feature names to file
dt <- xgb.model.dt.tree(feature_names = NULL, model = xgb)

write.table(x = dt, file = "model_dt_tree.txt",
  quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
```

To load in the model to 'repeat' the predictions I used:

```
xgb2 <- readRDS("xgb.model.rds")
xgb2 <- xgb.Booster.complete(xgb2)
```

There was more to it than that, but hopefully this will solve your immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  The dataset takes about a day and half to train, so I will report back when it is done.

Comment: I tried using rds to save the model.  It did not work, probably because I am using different versions of xgboost on different servers.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a hint that Jared said above, I was able to resolve my issue.  The problem seems to be that if you save an xgboost bin file, it does not keep the parameters used.  The solution is to load the parameters back in.  I tried saving the model to a json file but it crashed my rsession in each attempt.  So it would appear that bin is my only option.

The methodology is as follows (logistic-regression, gbtree):

```
bst <- xgboost(
                params = best.params
                , data = dtrain
                , nrounds = nrounds
                , early_stopping_rounds = early_stopping_rounds
                , nthread = nthread
                , num_parallel_tree = num_parallel_tree
                , eval_metric =  eval_metric
                , verbose = 2  
                , print_every_n = 1
)

min(predict(bst, dtest))
max(predict(bst, dtest))
xgb.save(bst, savefilemodelloc)
```

this produces:
min = 0.17932555079
max = 0.78802382946

now read the bin back in

```
remove(bst)
bst <- xgb.load(savefilemodelloc)
xgb.parameters(bst) <- best.params  # this loads the special parameters back in
min(predict(bst, dtest))
max(predict(bst, dtest))
```

this now produces:
min = 0.17932555079
max = 0.78802382946

Comment: Glad you solved it! Thanks for posting your answer (https://xkcd.com/979/)